# Is this book simplified or traditional?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

I'm learning Chinese and I would like to buy a book in simplified chinese.

I tried to look for "简体中文" but could not find it. Could you tell me if this is simplified?

http://www.huawenbookshop.com/1201443864.html

Comment: This is about the book, your questions has nothing to do with Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Simplified Chinese, as inferred by the text used on the cover.

Answer (score -1):

It is chinese. But I think this book may be a bit hard to understand because there are so many words that only appear in chinese mythology.

Comment: oh ok, thank you for the advice, I watched the drama and I liked it. I wanted to buy something I would like.

Comment: The question was whether it's simplified chinese or traditional, not whether it's Chinese or, say, Japanese :)

Comment: Not an answer, read the question again